# load json into object and access from remote file - plain javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to load several json files, store the responses in a global array, and access that array from yet another file.

So far I have the following:

on the page I creat the global object and include the callback function.

```
var globalObject = {};
function JsonCallback(j){
  globalObject.dataArray.push(j);
};
```

in the remote file I have the following

```
(function(){
  globalObject.dataArray = [];
  globalObject.urlArray = [
    'http://externaldomain.com.jsonp?uniqueID=1234&callback=JsonCallback',
    'http://externaldomain.com.jsonp?uniqueID=1235&callback=JsonCallback',
    'http://externaldomain.com.jsonp?uniqueID=1236&callback=JsonCallback',
    'http://externaldomain.com.jsonp?uniqueID=1237&callback=JsonCallback'
  ];
  var runFunction = function(index){
    console.log(index); 
    console.log(globalObject.dataArray[index]);
    // index doesn't match as files finish loading in different orders
  };

  var loadFunction = function(url, index){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = function(){
      runFunction(index);
    };
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  };

  var init = function(){
    for(var i = 0;i<globalObject.urlArray.length;i++){
      loadFunction(globalObject.urlArray[i], i);
    }
  }();

})();
```

for every url in the urlArray, I create a script element which loads the json file and fires the JsonCallback Function, storing the response in the global dataArray.

Once the file is loaded execute the runFunction, specific to the file just loaded. However, because the json files don't finish loading in the same order they were created, 'index' in runFunction doesn't always match the dataArray index.

Any ideas how to solve/avoid this problem would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is having this issue, this is how i got round it:

instead of hardcoding the JsonCallback function on to the page, I dynamically write a new callback function for each json call.

if anyone has a better solution, please let me know.